# Не удается найти файл в директории с исполняемым файлом

Tags: python

Подключил и создал файл. Написал в файл текст, но в директории около исполняемого файла python нет созданного тестового файла. После этого я осуществляю чтение файла, и он его читает без проблем, но опять же я не вижу его в директории рядом с файлом `main.py`.

Где он может быть и как создавать файл около файла с пайтоном?

```py
 f = open('text.txt' , 'w')
 f.write("start sesion")
 f.close()
 f = open('text.txt' , 'r')
 print(f.read())
 f.close()
```

консоль ошибки не выдаёт и читает файл без проблем: текст выводит.

Comment: Кстати я не в курсе, в пайтоне теперь роботы орудуют с файлами? О_о

Comment: @Effex да, наверно... не мог же автор ошибиться...

Comment: Как вы смотрели "деректоию"?

Comment: Кстати говоря, я только что запустил код, и этот файл я у себя в директории вижу, и все ок

Comment: Добавь 
`import os; print(os.path.abspath("text.txt"))`
Скорее всего у тебя рабочая директория не совпадает с папкой питоновского скрипта

Comment: Файл создаётся в текущей директории. И она может отличаться от той, где лежит ваш main.py.

Comment: сейчас посмотрю

Comment: @Alexander Goryushkin - ваша проверка показала что файл находится по пути C:\Users\GetWorld\text.txt

Comment: кстати кто знает я используюу библиотеку telethon и кстати она создаёт сесию при входе через `api` и файли сесии тоже в этой папке хотя должны в папке с файлом .

Comment: @Robert Все зависит от директории запуска python скрипта. Если скрипт запускается (по абсолютному пути) из каталога пользователя - все файлы без указания абсолютного пути будут сохраняться в каталоге пользователя. Текущая рабочая директория никак не связана с директорией нахождения скрипта. И может как совпадать, так и не совпадать с ней.

Comment: а вот я запускаю через консоль методом - `python  c://абсолютный путь`

Comment: понял спасибо , ещё последний вопрос кому не лень , можете посоветовать русурс по украшения cmd ?)